# Mongotemplate can't rename a collection

Tags: mongotemplate

I have a collection named `collection_One`. I want to rename the collection, but failed. `mongotemplate` showed me:

> **executing the 'renameCollection' command on the admin database"**

If I run:

`db.collection_one.renameCollection("collection_one","collection_two");` 
in the mongo shell, it works fine.

how to rename a collection by mongotemplate ?

This is the code where I'm trying it:

```
BasicDBObject basicObject = new BasicDBObject();
basicObject.append("renameCollection","collection_one");
basicObject.append("to","collection_two");
mongoTemplate.executeCommand(basicObject);
```

Comment: I've solved the problem. my code :                                                              DB db = mongoTemplate.getDb();
DBCollection dbCollection = db.getCollection('collection_one');
dbCollection.rename('collection_two', true);

Answer (score 4):

String dbName = default;//mongo db name

```
MongoNamespace mongoNamespace=new MongoNamespace(dbName,"collection_two");
mongoTemplate.getCollection("collection_one").renameCollection(mongoNamespace);
```

String boot version:2.1.4

Answer (score -1):

If you are using spring's mongo template then try this:
`mongoTemplate.getCollection(currName).rename(newName);`